# View State Error for Portal User

Tags: portal, viewstate

I am having visual force page and it accessed by both system administrator and portal user.

Now the visual force page is working fine in System administrator and its not working and getting View state error for portal user(Check the screen shot).

The portal user License is : Gold partner.

[image]

Could you please help me on this.

Thanks,
Krishna.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that for the portal user your page is querying more data (or you are doing something different in your testing) and simply exceeding the limit.  The [View State Inspector](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Winter11/View+State+Inspector) will let you examine the view state for the working case and from that you may be able to work out what is consuming the space.

Comment: Hi Keith C, Thanks for your reply. For Portal users we have no checkbox["Show View State in Development Mode"] in user information screen. So how to check the View state Inspector for portal user??

Comment: Oh sorry. Then instead inspecting the code may be the best way to go. Check your controller for large non-transient collections of data. Or a common problem is to (accidentally) include Attachment bodies that can be very large. You may need to introduce System.debug calls to track the problem down.